# Python reading jpg file from s3 unidentified image error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

```
#boto3 version = 1.28.3
#botocore version = 1.31.65

import boto3
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
new_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="path/to/image_folder/image_3.jpg")
image_dl = new_obj['Body'].read()
image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_dl))
```

Error:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: Cannot identify image file
```

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: I would start by debugging the object you are getting from s3. Make sure you are actually finding the image as expected, and then you can be sure if it is an s3 issue or a PIL issue.

Comment: Alternatively, download the file from S3 first, then access it as a local file.